# Using Qt 6 QPromise and QFuture

Tags: qt, qt6, qtconcurrent

I am trying to use Qt 6 QPromise (as described in https://www.qt.io/blog/asynchronous-apis-in-qt-6):

```
   QPromise<QByteArray> promise;
   QFuture<QByteArray> future = promise.future();

   promise.start();
   qDebug() << "Pre timer";
   QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, [p = std::move(promise)]()
   {
       qDebug() << "Timer triggered";
       p.finish(); // error
   });
```

But `p.finish()` triggers a compilation error:

```
error C2662: 'void QPromise<QByteArray>::finish(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const QPromise<QByteArray>' to 'QPromise<QByteArray> &'
```

Is the example code (from the blog entry) wrong, or did I miss something?

Regards,

Comment: [`QPromise::finish`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpromise.html#finish) is a non-`const` member so you need to declare your lambda as `mutable`.